# XAML: Why doesn't this trigger work?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, triggers

I'd like to use a trigger outside a style. **Edit**: whoops, sorry, it's actually inside a style for MainWindow, but I want the trigger to apply to the Ellipse and not MainWindow.

```
<Ellipse Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black">
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```

How do I fix the compiler error, which is "Cannot find the static member 'FillProperty' on the type 'MainWindow'"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to put this in style

```
<Ellipse  StrokeThickness="1" Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="black">
    <Ellipse.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="green"/>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Ellipse.Style>
```

Comment: This works. Does anyone know why triggers don't work outside of a Style? (How misleading it is that Ellipse has a Triggers collection that can't be used. If it only supports EventTriggers, it should have been named EventTriggers or the error message should say so.) And also, notice that this code doesn't assign Fill as an attribute of Ellipse, instead it uses a Setter tag to do the same thing. If Ellipse has a Fill attribute then the trigger stops working! Anyone know why?

Comment: Now I have another problem. If there is something else on top of the Ellipse then the ellipse color changes back when the mouse is on top of the inner object. Any idea how to keep the color change?

Comment: @Qwertie, if you set the Fill property in line (directly on the Ellipse), the Trigger's value will not be seen, and this is by design. Fill (and most other XAML properties of UI elements) is a DependencyProperty and there is a very specific order that determines the "actual" value when multiple things try to set the property (style setters, trigger setters, directly, etc). For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx under the **Dependency Property Value Precedence** section.

Answer (score 2):

In direct Triggers you need qualifying type names like so:

```
<Ellipse Width="100" Height="100">
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Ellipse.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Ellipse.Fill" Value="Yellow" />
        </Trigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```

This won't work though since direct triggers only allow `EventTriggers`, use a Style instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your window doesn't have a property named "Fill" like an Ellipse does. Maybe you mean "Background".

Comment: Ellipse doesn't have a Background. I want to set the Fill.

Comment: My point was that the style was being applied to the window, rather than to the ellipse.